# how get ViewData in page load using Asp.net MVC and javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to get ViewData in loaded page, using Asp.net MVC and javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a page load method in ASP.NET MVC. The view data and model is all accessible in the MVC `ViewPage` directly through the `ViewData` property because the `Controller` feeds the view page's `ViewData`.

Say you have a `MyController` in `MyProject/Controllers/MyController` with the following action:

```
public ActionResult Do() {
    ViewData["MyInt"] = 64;
    ViewData["MyString"] = "MyString";
    return View();
}
```

And in your `Do` view in `MyProject/Views/My/Do.aspx` you can access the viewdata directly:

```
<%= ViewData["MyInt"] %>
<%= ViewData["MyString"] %>
```

You can access them in the code-behind files as well because the viewpage inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` that has the `ViewData` property. You can read more about it [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-04-cs.aspx).